# C++, most efficient way to modulate sign (+/-) in an expression

Tags: c++, performance, operators, sign

I have an expression

```
x += y;
```

and, based on a boolean, I want to be able to change it to

```
x -= y;
```

Of course I could do

```
if(i){x+=y;} else{x-=y;}
//or
x+=(y*sign);  //where sign is either 1 or -1
```

But if I have to do this iteratively, I want to avoid the extra computation. Is there a more efficient way? Is it possible to modulate the operator?

Comment: No matter how you solve it it will require extra computation.

Comment: @Seth It is what it is. But what is the method of least computation?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to that.  The language doesn't specify the efficiency of computations.  Write straightforward code, and let the compiler optimize it for you.  If you find that there's a *measurable* and *significant* performance problem that can be traced to that particular operation, then consider tweaking the code.

Comment: @Matt typically (platform specific of course) an `if` is a `cmp` and `jne`, so it's pretty fast.

Comment: @Seth Cool. How does that generally compare to `x+=y` (or `-=`)?

Comment: ISTR that branching can be expensive if the processor is pipelining? Maybe that's outdated now though...

Comment: @Matt it doesn't really matter since the solution has to contain those (you are adding or subtracting no matter how you determine which one to do). If you just want to know for knowing, I would guess it's a `mov` and an `add` or `sub` (unless the `int` is already in a register, in which case I'd guess just an `add` or `sub`).

Comment: Do you have any control over the value of `i`? You could do `x += y^i` where `i` is either `0` or `~0`.

Comment: @mvds Say, good idea! <snerk> Though your math is off.

Comment: @Seth Alright, so the if ~doubles the compute time. Or do the different CPU instructions themselves differ in compute time?

Comment: sorry i was talking 1-s complement.

Comment: @Matt it may double the computation time, but that's like saying it doubles the weight when the weight was one grain of sand so now it's two. It's a _really small_ amount of time. And yes, for x86, instructions don't all take the same amount of time (as opposed to RISC in which they do).

Comment: Does i change during the iterations?  What about y?

Comment: If either one were constant throughout the loop it would be a much simpler problem and I doubt it would have been asked.

Comment: @Benjamin actually, i stays constant but y doesn't. I know i could just have duplicate functions for the code that contains this line, but I wanted to avoid duplication of code. is there another way?

Comment: Oh, `i` is constant? Hmm, I don't suppose it's known at compile time? Nah, that would be too easy :)

Comment: If you don't need to use `x` until the loop ends, then of course you could just add up all the values of `y` and then add or subtract at the end.

Comment: @Tom no, sorry, `i` is different for each function call, but never varies within the scope of the function. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Matt: If this is a performance-critical code, duplication may be the best answer. Code duplication is one of the optimizations that compilers do on a regular basis. Loop unrolling, for example. If this code isn't performance critical (have you done a profile of your application?), use whatever makes most sense to the human reader / human maintainer of the code.

Comment: @Tom Zych: actually, bit fiddling is fastest in a simple test. compensating for the off-by-one you'd get `x += (y^i)+(i&1);`, with `i=0` or `i=~0`, which is faster than any conditional construct I tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this iteratively is to **precompute** the data you need.

So, precomputation:

```
const YourNumberType increment  = (i? y : -y);
```

Then in your loop:

```
x += increment;
```

---

EDIT: re question in commentary about how to generate code, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display( int x ) { printf( "%d\n", x ); }

template< bool isSomething >
inline void advance( int& x, int y );

template<> inline void advance<true>( int& x, int y )   { x += y; }
template<> inline void advance<false>( int& x, int y )  { x -= y; }

template< bool isSomething >
void myFunc()
{
    int x   = 314;
    int y   = 271;

    for( ;; )
    {
        advance< isSomething >( x, y );     // The nano-optimization.
        display( x );
        if( !( -10000 < x && x < 10000 ) ) { return; }
    }
}

int main( int n, char*[] )
{
    n > 1? myFunc<true>() : myFunc<false>();
}
```

E.g. with Visual C++ 10.0 this generates two versions of `myFunc`, one with an `add` instruction and the other with a `sub` instruction.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I don't think the OP specified that `y` would be the same throughout the loop?

Comment: @Tom: right, he didn't specify anything about the boolean either. But then without any constraints it's a non-question.

Comment: @Alf yeah I failed to be explicit, but y will be different each iteration. Point taken though.

Comment: @Matt: well, that teaches you to be more precise when asking question. Is y actually going to vary? Is the condition going to vary? What depends on what? What is the *actual* problem? What exactly are you trying to optimize? Without this info the best you get is an answer to just code it straightforward and forget about the optimization you ask, which is what you marked as "solution".

Comment: @Matt: for example, if your condition is going to be the same, you can still apply the idea of precomputation. with different details, namely precomputation of code. but providing the solution details for you is impossible when you don't provide the problem details.

Comment: @Alf well I have a function that contains the line `x+=y` and `i` is constant for the duration of each call, while `y` varies for each iteration. Would precomputation of code then refer to having to two seperate functions?

Comment: Yes. You can write a single function template and instantiate for each of `false` and `true`, with the dynamic choice at the call site. However, the most important thing about optimization is to **MEASURE**, like, do you really need that added effort?

Comment: Ah, interesting idea. Or have a table of pointers to two functions.

Comment: @Alf its the 'workhorse' function of my neural network, which already goes too slow, and pausing in the debugger lands in the function in question (which is still pretty small) more than any other. Your function template solution definitely sounds like its what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear, using a function template allows me to avoid coding two nearly identical functions?

Comment: @Alf I thought a function template just allows one function to work with different types. How do you use it to change the code of the function based on a bool?

Comment: You can simply call this: `template< bool doAdd > inline void advance( int& x, int y )` instead of writing `+=` directly. With the `advance` function specialized differently for `false` and `true`. In a debug build with all optimization turned off this may generate a function call, so it's not a good idea to measure the debug build.

Comment: @Alf I definitely am not familiar enough with function templates. I've never seen a template with `<bool ...>` before. Also, what would the body of advance look like? How do you specialize a function?

Comment: @Alf Brilliant. I get it now. I didn't know about template specialization or non-type parameters before. Just one question, why does `advance()` take a reference for `x` but not `y`. Obviously `x` needs to be changed and `y` doesn't, but will not referencing `y` cause a copy of it to be allocated each time `advance` is called?

Answer (score 6):

```
if (i) {x += y;} else {x -= y;}
```

is probably going to be as efficient as anything else you can do.  `y * sign` is likely to be fairly expensive (unless the compiler can figure out that `y` is guaranteed to be 1 or -1).

Comment: I wouldn't say that this "probably" is a very good answer. I upvoted as being a reasonably good answer and as implying "don't sweat the small stuff" and also implying "premature optimization is the root of all evil". However, in order to actually have an answer to the question I provided my own (currently zero votes, he he). Cheers,

Comment: That would be a pretty smart compiler!

Comment: I agree with Alf, disagree with this answer. Not enough of a disagreement to downvote though.

Answer (score 2):

On a modern pipelined machine you want to avoid branching if at all possible in those cases where performance really does count. When the front of the pipeline hits a branch, the CPU guesses which branch to take and lets the pipeline work ahead based on that guess. Everything is fine if the guess was right. Everything is not so fine if the guess was wrong, particularly so if you're still using one of Intel's processors such as a Pentium 4 that suffered from pipeline bloat. Intel discovered that too much pipelining is not a good thing.

More modern processors still do use pipelining (the Core line has a pipeline length of 14 or so), so avoiding branching still remains one of those good things to do -- when it counts, that is. Don't make your code an ugly, prematurely optimized mess when it doesn't count.

The best thing to do is to first find out where your performance demons lie. It is not at all uncommon for a tiny fraction of one percent of the code base to be the cause of almost all of the CPU usage. Optimizing the 99.9% of the code that doesn't contribute to the CPU usage won't solve your performance problems but it will have a deleterious effect on maintenance.

You optimize once you have found the culprit code, and even then, maybe not. When performance doesn't matter, don't optimize. Performance as a metric runs counter to almost every other code quality metric out there.

So, getting off the soap box, let's suppose that little snippet of code is the performance culprit. Try both approaches and test. Try a third approach you haven't thought of yet and test. Sometimes the code that is the best performance-wise is surprisingly non-intuitive. Think Duff's device.

Comment: Don't *modern* pipelined machines have branch prediction?

Comment: @Tom: Yep, they do. But the prediction is still a guess, a guess that can be wrong. The very high cost of an incorrect guess (actions taken on the wrong path may have to be unwound, and then the pipeline restarted) was one of the reasons that Intel has been scaling down the length of the pipeline from the peak of 31 in the Pentium 4. The Core line has a pipeline length of 14, less than half the Pentium 4 length.

Comment: I'll add that modern CPUs also have a conditional move operation (e.g. cmov) which avoids having to flush the pipeline when a misprediction happens at the cost of (usually about) 1 clock cycle. A compiler can not statically know how often a prediction will be wrong. But if you know that the branch will be predicted correctly about 90+% of the time, then a conditional jump would still be more efficient than the cmov. Of course, going down to assembly level should only happen after you've profiled and determined that this could make a reasonable improvement.

Answer (score 2):

**If** `i` stays constant during the execution of the loop, and `y` doesn't, move the `if` outside of the loop.

So instead of...

```
your_loop {
    y = ...;
    if (i)
        x += y;
    else
        x -= y;
}
```

...do the following....

```
if (i) {
    your_loop {
        y = ...;
        x += y;
    }
}
else {
    your_loop {
        y = ...;
        x -= y;
    }
}
```

BTW, a decent compiler will do that optimization for you, so you may not see the difference when actually benchmarking.

Comment: Yes I thought of that and it's probably what I will do. But the loop I'm working with is actually larger than that and I was hoping to avoid duplication of code (since its only one operator out of many lines of code that has to change).

Comment: @Matt You'll often find that performance requires verbosity (which, in this case, you should be able to minimize by sensible use of inline functions). BTW, if your loop is sufficiently large, you'll probably find more optimization opportunities in that "large" piece (that you haven't shown us) than trying to squeeze every last drop out of this very simple piece of logic (which compiler probably did for you anyway). Bottlenecks are to be measured, not assumed! Also, consider splitting your problem into sub-problems that can be solved concurrently.

Comment: @Matt, well, you simply put the common portions of these 2 loops in a function (or functions), as you would with any other code that needs to be reused in more than one place. You just make sure the function body is available to be inlined by the compiler, making a function call overhead disappear and producing the machine code that is identical to what it would be if code was actually repeated in these 2 loops. If you compiler refuses to do the inlining on its own (function too large), you can often use compiler-specific facilities to force it (such as `__forceinline` under Visual C++).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to avoid branching and multiplication. Let's say the switch `i` is set to all `1` bits, same size as `y`, when you want to add, and to `0` when you want to subtract. Then:

```
x += (y & i) - (y & ~i)
```

Haven't tested it, this is just to give you the general idea. Bear in mind that this makes the code a lot harder to read in exchange for what would probably be a very small increase in efficiency.

Edit: or, as bdonlan points out in the comments, possibly even a decrease.

Comment: Given all the data dependencies there, I highly doubt that will be more efficient. Do you have any benchmark numbers?

Comment: @bdonlan: Of course not, I didn't even test it. It's just the only way I can see to avoid both branching and multiplication. Not sure what you mean about data dependencies?

Comment: @Tom I haven't really used binary operators, can't really figure out how the code works. Interesting though.

Comment: Basically it just zeroes out the one you don't want. Using bitwise operators can be more efficient than multiplying sometimes.

Comment: @Tom, data dependencies are when assembly-level operations depend on each other's results. This reduces CPU-level parallelism. In your case, you have to compute, in order, a bitwise NOT, AND, SUB, then ADD again. Branches (ie ifs) are expensive because they introduce a control dependency, but when you layer data dependencies this thick, they can be more expensive than the `if` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I put my suggestion in the comments to the test, and in a simple test bit-fiddling is faster than branching options on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5520 @ 2.27GHz, but slower on my laptop Intel Core Duo.

If you are free to give `i` either the value `0` (for +) or `~0` (for -), these statements are equivalent:

```
// branching:
if ( i ) sum -= add; else sum += add;
sum += i?-add:add;
sum += (i?-1:1)*add;

// bit fiddling:
sum += (add^i)+(i&1);
sum += (add^i)+(!!i);
sum += (i&~add)-(i&add);
```

And as said, one method can beat the other by a factor of 2, depending on CPU and optimization level used.

Conclusion, as always, is that benchmarking is the only way to find out which is faster in your particular situation.